# No render output node in scene

Tags: node-editor

I am new to using blender and have been watching youtube videos on how to use it. I copied the steps of how to create cracks in a surface. I can see what it looks like if it gets rendered but then when I go to render it I get the message "no render output node in scene". It's not an animation, it's just a single image. Here is a screenshot of all my nodes and the error after trying to get it to render.
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is because you removed the composite output in the compositing node tree accidentally. I'll write up an answer with more detail.

Comment: You just beat me to it. i am sure that is what it is.

Comment: @shaunify Glad to help. I hate to ask this, but if my answer solved your issue, could you please accept it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you removed the composite node accidentally in the composite node tree.

[image]

Select the composite node tree button (highlighted left).

At this point, we should take a step back, and make sure that what I think is happening, is happening.

There are two signs that I'm wrong:

1. Use Nodes isn't enabled
2. There is a composite node

If both of those aren't true, then continue.

Now there are two ways you could solve this.

#### #1

You could disable Use Nodes. When this is disabled, anything in the compositing node tree is ignored.

#### #2

Or you could add in a composite node, and attach it to the Render Layers node.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> output -> composite.

[image]

And then attaching the render layers node to it.

[image]

Comment: To add to TARDIS Maker, sometimes the problem is that you don't have a Material Output node in your material. Add one: `Shift+A >> Output >> Material Output`

Comment: Also try unchecking "Sequencer" in Output Properties >> Post Processing. Worked for me.