# Audio visualisation

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, audio

I have created a simple grid with a wave modifier, It looks like this right now.

I want to have the wave be manipulated by audio. does anyone know how i can import audio tracks into blender and have it "communicate" with the wave modifier?

using animation nodes this is how far i came:

[image]

Nothing is happening any tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two ways I know.

Set a key on a parameter of the modifier, and use the [Bake Sound to F-crurve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZQGzkpCTFU). But it's really limited.

Or use [Animation Nodes](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which has actual precise animation controls an hu_ge possibilities based on sound.
Actually, in its [*Bake Sound* node documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes/v2_0/sound.html), you can see an example setup looking like what you want:

[image: demo gif]

Comment: The nodes seem like a great option, but as a newby how do i insert one of these nodes? i just see nodes that correspond to textures

Comment: Check the Animation Node link I provided, everything needed is explained there.

Comment: I updated my question, do you know what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: you forgot to check the Mesh Data in your Mesh Object Output (far right node).

Comment: @Juriaan Also, if you are using version 2.1, connecting the edge indices is a must. So, make sure you do.

Comment: Thanks guys! i checked the node. and connected the edges and now it works! cheers to you both

Comment: 1 more thing, while rendering it says: no output node detected how do i fix that>

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42607/no-render-output-node-in-scene